# Notepad++ - Line Operations on 2 lines at a time

Tags: html

I am wanting to do the following line operation in Notepad++ (for unix):

## FROM

Test 1 
Stop 1 
Test 2 
Stop 2 
Test 3 
Stop 3 
Test 4 
Stop 4 
Test 5 
Stop 5

## TO

Test 1 Stop 1 
Test 2 Stop 2 
Test 3 Stop 3 
Test 4 Stop 4 
Test 5 Stop 5

I haven't been able to find a working regex string and other option(s) yet.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research for you and came along this answer it might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811198/9026200

Comment: Answers that just contain links to the solution are often frowned upon here. While it does lead to a Stack Exchange website, if it was any external website, it would be possible for your answer to become practically pointless if the website went down. You should write the essential details of the linked answer by either quoting it or writing it in your own words.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is:

search: `^(.*)\r?\n(.*)$` (make sure the checkbox ". matches newline" is unchecked)

replace: `\1 \2`

**How this works**

`^` matches the beginning of the line. `(.*)` matches any content and stores it in group 1, such that we can get it again later using `\1`. Note that the `.` does not match the linebreak at the end of the line as long as we have not checked the ". matches newline" checkbox in Notepad++. `\r?\n` matches the linebreak you would like to remove. `(.*)` matches any content again and stores it in group 2, such that we can get it again later using `\2`. `$`then matches the end of a line.

*Hint*

Although this is not directly helping your question, it is still good to know that lines can be joined in Notepad++ using CTRL+J.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much hanjo, especially for the 'how this works' section. (:*) ...

Comment: mind accept this as the answer then?